# How to add rows to specific section in tableview with dictionary?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dictionary

I have a dictionary and importing information from my database. I need to put it specifically in the right section in my table view. All the information is provided, if you need more detail or code I will provide it.

Dictionary output `["March 27": ["do the dishes", "take out the trash"], "March 29": ["Walk the dog", "Water the plants"], "March 28": ["Clean the house"]]`

```
var date = ["March 27", "March 28", "March 29"]

 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return date.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return date[section]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! Chores
    //Having trouble on what to do here
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how you can do, I think this is self explanatory:

```
var output = ["March 27": ["do the dishes", "take out the trash"], "March 29": ["Walk the dog", "Water the plants"], "March 28": ["Clean the house"]]
var date = Array(output.keys)

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return date.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return date[section]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return output[date[section]]?.count ?? 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! Chores
    var value = output[date[indexPath.section]]?[indexPath.row] ?? ""
    cell.textLabel.text = value
    return cell
}
```

// Edited in number of rows you have:

```
output[date[section]]?.count
```

it's exactly like this, this mostly gives you optionals but I will ignore it in this example:

```
let keyForSection = date[section]
let arrayOfStringsForKey = output[keyForSection]
let numberOfRows = arrayOfStringsForKey.count
```

you do similar stuff to get the actual value but instead of count you pass index of the row you want the value from

```
let value = arrayOfStringsForKey[rowNumber]
```

Comment: How would I pick up the count for the number of arrays under a key? i.e. `"March 27" : ["...."], ["???"], "March 29": ....`

Comment: Also does date go through each key? Because for me it only picks up the first one "March 27"

Comment: output[YOUR_KEY]?.count - Is it what you asking?

Comment: Yes but do I need to loop through `Array(output.keys)` to get the count for each section?

Comment: Still having problems I need to go through each section March 27, 28, and 29 and get the number of Arrays inside each key.

Comment: In your example with tables view you don't need to loop through the array to get each section count because table view give you section number or index path and you just need to call count property on array object as in the example I posted. However if you have some other requirements you may need to loop through the array to get he number of Array items.